# Getting data from cursor and store it in string array

Tags: java, android

```
ID| TOPIC | TITLE | TYPE | NAME |
---------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref  | Ferari|
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref  | TOYOTA|
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref| AUDI |
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD    | ref| BMW  |
---------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | ref  | NISSAN|
----------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | ref  | SUZKI|
----------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | ref| TATA |
```

Cursor hold data like this table. Now, I want get data like `ID| TOPIC | TITLE | TYPE | NAME |` here `NAME` can be multiple according to the `ID`. Like for `ID` 1 K will be `FERARI,TOYOTA,AUDI,BMW` and so on. I want to show this information in `customlistview` in a row .

My question is

is there any way to store the name data in String Array or do you have any alternative suggestion for me

Comment: Do you want to have a collection of objects like `{ Id, Cars }`? Also your code doesn't do anything useful and looks wrong.

Comment: there are multiple non-unique IDs?!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to store your values from your database table in arrays? For that, you could create parallel resizeable generic lists like this:

```
ArrayList<int> ids = new ArrayList<int>(); 
ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And you can then add items to it like this:

```
ids.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
topics.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOPIC")));
titles.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE")));
types.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TYPE")));
names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME")));
```

P.S. your database looks wrong - values in ID column should be unique, if ID is the primary key (it looks like it should be).

P.S.P.S
Another option would be to use Object-Oriented design - Create a class that has members like id, topic, title, type, name and so on.

Comment: I tried with stringList.add(getID, getName); but it throws indexoutofboundexception. The data I got here by joining two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String topic;
    private String title;
    private String type;
    private String name;

    public Product(Cursor cursor) {
        this.id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        this.topic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOPIC"));
        this.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE")); 
        this.type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TYPE"));
        this.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));
    }

    //Getter & Setter here...
}
```

this Product could be in a list of Products like:

```
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
Product product = new Product(cursor);

products.add(product); // or simpler: products.add(new Product(cursor);
```

and you could use this list for many purposes like:

```
ArrayList<int> ids = new ArrayList<int>(); 
ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Product product : products) {
    // for every product in your products list do:  
    ids.add(product.getId);
    topics.add(product.getTopic);
    titles.add(product.getTitle);
    types.add(product.getType);
    names.add(product.getName);
}
```